# Folder creation using bat command

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file to create folder.

```
:X3Main
IF EXIST "%1%\JBoss" goto Test
IF EXIST "%1%\DB" goto DB
goto end

:Test
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\JBoss"
goto end

:DB
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\DB"
goto end
```

here first folder is created successfully(IF EXIST "%1%\JBoss" goto Test) but second function is not working. If I remove first function then second function is working.

Please can you someone explain reason behind this?

Comment: the intention of the code you posted is not clear.  please explain better what are you trying to do with an example including the folder structure. Also, check some of the answers below they give you a couple of hints: 1. be careful with the differences between `%1`,  `%1%`, `%~1` and `"%~1"`. And 2. be careful about the differences between `goto end` and `goto :eof`, and between `goto` and `call`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
:X3Main
IF EXIST "%1%\JBoss\" call:Test
IF EXIST "%1%\DB\" call:DB
goto :eof &rem or goto:end or where you want

:Test
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\JBoss"
goto :eof

:DB
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\DB"
goto :eof
```

use `call` to return from function and `goto:eof` to end a function.
Edited concerning foxidrive's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra info: In the NT line of Windows for a reliable test for a folder you need to end the foldername with a backslash

and you may have meant %~1 instead of %1%

```
IF EXIST "%~1\JBoss\" do task
```

and in your case you can always use this which will do nothing if the folder already exists: the `2>nul` eliminates a harmless error message when the folder exists.

```
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\JBoss" 2>nul
mkdir "%DESTINATION%\IX3\COSMIC\DB" 2>nul
```